# Convergent matrix solver code, theory behind.

Tags: convergence-divergence, matrix-calculus

I'm looking for some help understanding how this peace of code checks convergence in a matrix.

The code just loops the inner matrix (1 - n-1) and applies the formula 0.2 ( C + A + B + D + E) storing the difference in a variable and later dividing by the matrix size and compares against a defined tolerance.

[image]

Source: http://nsfcac.rutgers.edu/people/irodero/classes/13-14/ece451-566/assignment1.pdf

```
void solve(double **A, int n)
{
   int convergence=FALSE;
   double diff, tmp;
   int i,j, iters=0;
   int for_iters;


   for (for_iters=1;for_iters<21;for_iters++) 
   { 
     diff = 0.0;

     for (i=1;i<n;i++)
     {
       for (j=1;j<n;j++)
       {
         tmp = A[i][j];
         A[i][j] = 0.2*(A[i][j] + A[i][j-1] + A[i-1][j] + A[i][j+1] + A[i+1][j]);         
         diff += fabs(A[i][j] - tmp);
       }
     }

     iters++;     
     if (diff/((double)N*(double)N) < Tolerance){
        convergence=TRUE;        
     } 
     printf("iteration is %u\n", for_iters);
    } /*for*/

}
```

The thing is what is the theory under this convergent check?

Any comment will be useful!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the discretization of $\Delta A=A$ on a grid with step size $h=1$. The resulting linear system is diagonally dominant, the algorithm is an implementation of the Gauß-Seidel iteration, which converges at least geometrically with factor $0.8$.